# Needs suggestion for graphic designing study

Tags: education

I am freelancer graphic designer and I have got skills by learning some tutorials and some videos. I have got some experience in designing logos and brand identities but I always feel that some pieces of puzzle are missing.

I want to study Graphic Designing, Web Designing, App Designing etc...
I have seen a site named **Digital Tutors**. It provides learning path to learn a subject clearly, means you can have complete road map of study. I don't want to study at home, I want to study at university so my question is simple.

What are the courses to learn to be a professional designer?
**or**
What a professional Designing Direct of a agency has learnt?

*I hope this question is now clear*

Comment: You want to find a college or university that offers degree programs in Fine Arts/Graphic Design/User Experience design?

Comment: @da01 I will find universities or collages myself but want to know which course to select. Like you have mentioned three courses. What is different between Fine Arts, Graphic Design and User Experience Design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your interests. What you have mentioned is three different field i.e., graphic designing, web designing and app designing. I don't think you can get all three in a single training course. Again in graphic designing you have 2d and 3d designing either of which require unique software to be learned. It can be possible to have knowledge in all but it is advisable to be an expert in a unique field if you want that to be your career. First realize which one you are passionate about.Then you can decide the course.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my question. I am passionate about designing corporate identities i.e. Logo, Business card, Flayer...

Comment: You should try to excel yourself in Illustrator, Photoshop and In Design. If you are good at drawing try to learn using stylus to create arts and find the plugins for Photoshop and Illustrator you are comfortable with. Learn color management and calibration, which is essential if you are gonna make designs that will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of programs you could seek out. Typical ones would include:

- Graphic Design
- User Experience Design
- Interaction/Interactive Design

Graphic Design programs would lean more towards the fine arts realm. User Experience programs may lean towards psychology and library sciences. Interaction/Interactive Design my lean more towards computer science.

As for what *courses* to take, that's all going to be dependent on the particular school and program you enroll in.